# enqueuing my styles and scripts in wordpresss

Tags: wordpress, enqueue

here is my functions.php code to enqueue the scripts and styles:

```
// Add scripts and stylesheets
function first_afro_theme_scripts() {
    wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' ); // deregisters the default WordPress jQuery  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'first-theme-bootstrap', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css', array(), '3.3.5' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'first-theme-blog', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/first-theme-blog.css', array(), '3.3.6');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'first-theme-bootstrap-script', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), '3.3.5', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'first_afro_theme_scripts' );
```

In the header.php file i have added,

But but when i go to view page source i dont see any of these styles and scripts. I made sure the path are correct.

in my plugins folder, it is a little different.
here is the code to enqueue the function:

```
// Enqueue the custom JavaScript file
function newsletter_afro_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Enqueue jQuery
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/assets/js/jquery-3.6.0.js', array(), '3.6.0', true );
    
    // Enqueue the custom CSS file
    wp_enqueue_style( 'newsletter-style', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/assets/css/style.css', array(), '1.0.0', 'all' );
    
    // Enqueue the custom JavaScript file
    wp_enqueue_script( 'newsletter-script', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) . 'includes/assets/js/newsletter-script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'newsletter_afro_enqueue_scripts' );
```

on view page source, i see the newsletter-style-css but not the script. the scripts files are not working. what am i doing wrong?

I have checked my code many many times. I have checked the path to the files and confirm it is correct. I have looked up on tutorials to see what i am doing wrong i still can't. I have cleared my cache.

Answer (score 0):

The script files are being instructed to print in the footer, which is dependent on the `wp_footer()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_footer/)/[hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_footer/) and [the `wp_print_footer_scripts` action hook](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_print_footer_scripts/). Check that your `footer.php` has `wp_footer` (action or function) or the `wp_print_footer_scripts` action.

You can also remove the last parameter from `wp_enqueue_script()` (`true`), and that should print the scripts in the header.

Comment: Hello @celeb. Thank you for your respond. i actually have wp_footer() in footer.php. But I can't find the script files. I see all the styles(CSS) files not the js fies

Comment: @celeb thanks alot. I actually checked and i had removed the hook because I did not want to be seeing the admin navbar